# How to get result from pipeline by using service.stack.redis

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, pipeline

The question is, I want to get the result of the queuecommand after the pipeline flush, however I don't know how to get the result by using the servicestack redis

for example:

```
 pipeline.QueueCommand(r => r.Get<string>("foo"));
 pipeline.Flush();
```

where should I get the result of "foo", so that I can pass back the result to others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [the Wiki Page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisTransactions) about transactions on GitHub.

Especially, this example

```
int callbackResult;
using (var trans = redis.CreateTransaction())
{
  trans.QueueCommand(r => r.Increment("key"));  
  trans.QueueCommand(r => r.Increment("key"), i => callbackResult = i);  

  trans.Commit();
}
//The value of "key" is incremented twice. The latest value of which is also stored in 'callbackResult'.
```

There is a virtual method with a callback, that will give you the result.

```
public virtual void QueueCommand(Func<IRedisClient, string> command, Action<string> onSuccessCallback, Action<Exception> onErrorCallback).
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. But if I want to get all the results of many QueueCommand, can I only do like this and collect them all? And I'm not sure if commit and flush is synchronous or not, will my main thread be blocked when executing those commands?